# Issues with addclass and selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty green with jQuery so I'm sure this is an obvious error - but nonetheless it has me stumped. I'm trying to make a pretty simple navbar that shifts from 500px down the page to absolute positioning at the top after you scroll past it.

The issue: I can't seem to get the js to find the navbar when I'm using a div ID of navbar and a selector of #navbar.

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        var scrollDepth = 500;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollDepth) {
            $('#navbar').addClass('fixed')
        } else {
            $('#navbar').removeClass('fixed')
        }
    })
})
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ayGwn/475/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an issue with specificty. A CSS rule for an id will override a CSS rule for a class. If you change the `.fixed { ... }` to `#navbar.fixed { .. }` it should work. Assuming you are not using `.fixed` for anything else.

[MDN article about CSS selectors specificty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

> The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:
>
> - Universal selectors
> - Type selectors
> - Class selectors
> - Attributes selectors
> - Pseudo-classes
> - ID selectors
> - Inline style

Comment: beat me as well, deleted my answer as the answer is here. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should use `#navbar.fixed`, instead of `.fixed` only. Because `id` style gets more priority than `class` style. In your case javascript is working fine. the `.fixed` class is being added. But as you have defined `position:absolute` for you `#navbar` `id`, it is overriding style rules for `.fixed` class.